# How to change other input field when select box is choosen?

Tags: jquery

This is my form.

When I select some item and write some kg, then price should be automatically changed. Like

```
potato - 1 kg - Rs 100 | Tomato - 1 kg - Rs 90 | Onion - 1 kg - 80
```

Here I want to check condition if item is selected as 1 then price should 100, if item is selected as 2 then price should be 90 and if item is selected 3 then price should be onion.

```js
// I have created new function like this.
// But How to use this function to check condition ?

function conversion_kg(item) {

  rate = [
    ["0", 100],
    ['1', 90],
    ['2', 80],
  ];

  return rate[item];
}

function updatedynamicprice(value) {
  let kg = $("input[name='kg[]']").val();
  let total_price=conversion_to_kg(value)[1]*kg;
  
  let price = $("input[name='price[]']").val(total_price);
}

$(document).on('change', ".item", function() {
  updatedynamicprice($(this).val());
  conversion_bag_to_kg($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control item" name="item[]">
  <option value="1">Potato</option>
  <option value="2">Tomato</option>
  <option value="3">Onion</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="kg[]" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="price[]" class="form-control">
```

Comment: "Price should be onion?"

Comment: I made you a snippet. It gives very descriptive errors. Fix them please

Comment: What does `"0"` in `["0", 100],` means inside `rate` Array?

Comment: yes i have declared price inside array ?
but how to use when to multiply with kg ? can i use like this conversion_bag_to_kg(value)[1]

Comment: @BeginnerCoder I don't understand correctly, is the `rate` array... what? Prices-per-kg ? what are the `"0" '1' '2'` for?

Comment: id  and price.When item is selected it should return price

Comment: I am just trying only.I am just beginner so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use a common parent element
- Use an Array `items` to store your data as Object `{name: "Potato", price: 100.00}`
- Use `parseFloat()` when handling String to float conversion. (Getting a `Element.value`, or with jQuery `$element.val()` will always give you a String!)
- Generate your `<option>` elements dynamically. That way you're sure to reflect your JS data into HTML
- Store the price value inside the `<option>` `value` attribute.

```js
const items = [
  {name: "Potato", price: 100.00},
  {name: "Tomato", price: 90.00},
  {name: "Onion",  price: 80.50}
];

$(".productCalc").each(function() {

  const $item  = $('[name="item[]"]', this);
  const $kg    = $('[name="kg[]"]', this);
  const $price = $('[name="price[]"]', this); 
  
  // Generate Option elements
  $item.html(items.reduce((html, i) => html += `<option value="${i.price}">${i.name}</option>`, ""));
  
  // Calculate when $item or $kg value changes
  $item.add($kg).on("input", function() {
    const price = parseFloat($item.val());
    const kg = parseFloat($kg.val()) || 0;
    const result = price * kg;
    const priceFormatted = result.toFixed(2);
    $price.val(`€ ${priceFormatted}`);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<div class="productCalc">
  <select class="form-control" name="item[]"></select>
  <label>Kg: <input class="form-control" name="kg[]" type="text"></label>
  <label>Price: <input class="form-control" name="price[]" type="text" readonly></label>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```